# Naming a file the content of a Text Entry Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, rename

I am trying to create a program in tkinter that allows people to rename a log file to whatever is typed into a text entry box. However this is not going to plan.

EDITED Thanks to Bryan Oakley.

I have slaved the rename function to a button however my new issue is that the values for contents are a weird set of numbers. These appear to be randomly generated every time I run the rename function.

These numbers look like

44499952get

44452520get

46401376get

46400496get

44688048get

44697440get

Can anyone please help or explain what these numbers mean?

Comment: Are you putting the brackets after the `get`?

Comment: You're going to have to show us code. It's impossible to guess what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
newname_ent = Entry(self,width = 50,)
contents = newname_ent.get()
```

It seems highly unlikely that the user will be able to type in something in the millisecond or so between creating the widget and getting the value.

You need to create a button or set an event binding that will call a function after the user has the chance to enter some information. That function is where you will put the code to do the rename.